# how do we change the default repo Cypress looks for its binary installation?

Tags: cypress

I have previously installed Cypress 7.2.0 and now need to upgrade to 13.6.6.

I uninstalled all cached Cypress installation using `cypress cache clear` and installed cypress 13.6.6 using

```
npm install -g cypress@13.6.6
```

With `cypress cache list`, I can verify there is only one cypress version installed, 13.6.6.

But when I ran `cypress open`, I got the following error message:

```
No version of Cypress is installed in: /Users/xxxx/Library/Caches/Cypress/7.2.0/Cypress.app

Please reinstall Cypress by running: cypress install

----------

Cypress executable not found at: /Users/xxxx/Library/Caches/Cypress/7.2.0/Cypress.app/Contents/MacOS/Cypress
```

I have tried running `export CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=<path_to_cypress_binary>` first then `cypress open` AND `CYPRESS_RUN_BINARY=/Users/xxxx/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress cypress open`, but neither worked.

I am on MacOS. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-g` option is not usually used with Cypress. You would install to each project and the Cypress binaries install part into `/Users/xxxx/Library/Caches/Cypress`, part into project `node_modules`.

With `-g` option you now have a version in node global that may be interfering with your project install.

- Check `npm root -g` to find the path to node globals folder, check for Cypress and delete (all versions)
- Remove `node_modules` from project
- Update `package.json` to the the required Cypress version
- Run `npm install` to reinstate `node_modules`